# message text formatting for Facebook channel

Tags: c#

I am sending a message that requires some basic formatting, mainly newline characters.

The message displays fine in the emulator and the web client but the newline characters are ignored in the Facebook message.

```
await context.PostAsync($"{BotResponses.IntroText}\n{BotResponses.IntroTip}");
```

How can I format the text so that it works in Facebook as well?

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work I had to use a `StringBuilder` and use the `AppendLine` method.

Using `Environment.NewLine` didn't work and neither did `\r\n`